# Does convergence in measure imply convergence in mean?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Here is the proposition. I doubt if the author's proof is correct.

$\mathscr{L}^{1}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{R})$ is the set of all real-valued ([rather than $[-\infty,+\infty]$] -valued) integrable functions on $X$.

## ==============

[image]

## ==============

The first part of the proof is easy. But I doubt whether the second part is correct. That is to say, when these assumptions are satisfied, does convergence in measure imply convergence in mean?

The red line part is confusing. In Royden's **Real Analysis**, the red line part is true when the assumption $\mu(X)<+\infty$ is added. See Corollary 19 below. However, Cohn doesn't give this assumption.

## ==============

[image: Royden's Real Analysis]

## ==============

For the second part of proof, is Cohn's approach correct? Do we need the assumption that the measure is finite?

Comment: I'm confused why Cohn argues that **If $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to $f$ in measure, then every subsequence of $\{f_{n}\}$ has a subsequence converges to $f$ almost everywhere.** Why does Cohn use the word **EVERY**?

Comment: If you start with the whole sequence $\{f_n\}$ you will only get  a subsequence which converges in the mean. We have to show that $\{f_n\}$ itself converges in the mean, not some subsequence. So the idea is to you the following: a sequence of real numbers converges to $0$ iff EVERY subsequence of it has a further sub sequence which converges to $0$.

Comment: Thank you, @Kavi Rama Murthy! That's the point!! You are a great teacher!!

Comment: It would surprise me if Cohn's book co tained a mistake (at least the second edition). He is a great author imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any measure space if  a sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges in measure then there is a subsequence which converges almost everywhere. The given measure need not be finite. Proof: choose $k_n$ such that $k_n <k_{n+1}$ and  $\mu \{x:|f_{k_n}(x)-f(x)| >\frac 1 {2^{n}}\} <\frac 1 {2^{n}}$. Then $\sum_n \mu\{x:|f_{k_n}(x)-f(x)| >\frac 1 {2^{n}}\} <\infty$. This implies that $\mu (\lim \sup \{x:|f_{k_n}(x)-f(x)| >\frac 1 {2^{n}}\}=0$. it follows that $f_{k_n} \to f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, Kavi Rama Murthy!! Your approach is so concise. **Theorem: If $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to $f$, then there is a subsequence of $\{f_{n}\}$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere.** This theorem is easy to prove. However, I'm confused why Cohn argues that **If $\{f_{n}\}$ converges to $f$ in measure, then every subsequence of $\{f_{n}\}$ has a subsequence converges to $f$ almost everywhere.** Why does Cohn use the word **EVERY**?

Comment: A sequence of real numbers converges to 00 iff **EVERY** subsequence of it has a further sub sequence which converges to 0. Thank you, Kavi Rama Murthy!! That's the point!! You are a great teacher!!

Answer (score 0):

The part underlined in red does not require the measure space to be finite. It is mostly a consequence of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, which works in any measure space. It's a bit vague, but I always remember it as "if a sequence of functions converges in measure fast enough, then it converges almost everywhere" and taking subsequences lets you increase the rate of convergence.

Comment: But Borel-Cantelli lemma requires that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_{n})<\infty$.